# Confusion with forked process?

Tags: c, multiprocessing

I am trying to do first child function, for example, printing out a string : hello!, and go back to parent process. Then, I forked anothrer n processes for the second child function, which will count the shared memory number. I suppose there only shows one "all done" in the end, but it shows two? thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define NUM_LINES 5

char * shm;

void child_func(char *shm)
{ 
        while (atoi(shm) != NUM_LINES)
        {
            // P(sem);
            printf("now reading word:%d\n", atoi(shm) );
            *shm+=1;
            // V(sem);
        }

        exit(0);
}

void parent_func(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid_wait;
    do
    {
        pid_wait = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    }while (pid_wait != pid);
    // printf("Process %d done\n", getppid());
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* declarations */
    pid_t pid[8]; 
    int ret, shmid, status,corpse, i, ave, n;
    char fn[20];
    key_t key = 123;
    char *string_back;

    /* create share memory */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT|666)) <0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* attach shm */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char*)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* init shm value */
    *shm = '0';

    /* input */
    printf("please enter n:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /*  section 1  */
        pid[0] = fork();
        if (pid[0] == 0) // child processes
        {
            printf("hello !\n");
        }
        else if (pid[0] >0)
        {
            parent_func(pid[0]);
        }

    /*  section 2 */
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0) // child processes
        {
                child_func(shm);
        }
        else if (pid[i] >0)
        {
            parent_func(pid[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("all done\n");
    /* detach shm */
    shmdt(shm);
    /* destroy shm */
    int retval = shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    if (retval < 0) perror("remove shm");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first child process in 'section 1' is not terminated earlier.

Comment: ok, I know that it might not terminate earlier, but why it print out "all done" two times?

Comment: Because the first child process reaches the "all done" statement (as it doesn't terminate before then) and then the parent process, after it waits on all the children, also reaches the statement later.

Comment: But, in my parent process, I only let it wait for the child process and do nothing..?

Comment: The first child gets to the "all done" statement. It doesn't matter if the parent process waits for it - the child *already executed the "all done" statement* before the process ended normally by running off the end of the main function. The other children call `exit(0)` and so they terminate early, without a chance to ever execute "all done". The second "all done" message is from the parent process, after all the children have terminated. (To verify this: also print out the PID in the "all done", "hello" and "row reading" output.)

Comment: ok, I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that if you had a number in shared memory, you'd see twice as many child processes as you expected.  Since you get `0` back from `atoi(shm)` at the moment, you don't notice this. With multiple processes like this, it is often a good idea to prefix every print operation with the process ID of the process executing it — it typically makes it much easier to know/debug which process is doing what.

Comment: Do you mean I should use mutex or semaphore to lock it..?

Comment: I mean that unless I've managed to misread the code, the only assignment to the contents of the shared memory is `*shm = '\0';` so there's an empty string in it so `atoi(shm)` will return 0.  Eventually, if you're using the shared memory for interprocess communication, you will need to worry about synchronization between reading and writing processes to ensure coherent access to the memory; however, in the short term, nothing except the parent process is writing to shared memory, and it does that before the children are created, so there is (as yet) no synchronization problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding exit(0) in first section, I only get one "all done" in the last, which is the answer I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define NUM_LINES 5

char * shm;

void child_func(char *shm)
{ 
        while (atoi(shm) != NUM_LINES)
        {
            // P(sem);
            printf("now reading word:%d\n", atoi(shm) );
            *shm+=1;
            // V(sem);
        }

        exit(0);
}

void parent_func(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid_wait;
    do
    {
        pid_wait = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    }while (pid_wait != pid);
    // printf("Process %d done\n", getppid());
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* declarations */
    pid_t pid[8]; 
    int ret, shmid, status,corpse, i, ave, n;
    char fn[20];
    key_t key = 123;
    char *string_back;

    /* create share memory */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT|666)) <0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* attach shm */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char*)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* init shm value */
    *shm = '0';

    /* input */
    printf("please enter n:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /*  section 1  */
        pid[0] = fork();
        if (pid[0] == 0) // child processes
        {
            printf("hello !\n");
            /* problem solved here */
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid[0] >0)
        {
            parent_func(pid[0]);
        }

    /*  section 2 */
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0) // child processes
        {
                child_func(shm);
        }
        else if (pid[i] >0)
        {
            parent_func(pid[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("all done\n");
    /* detach shm */
    shmdt(shm);
    /* destroy shm */
    int retval = shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    if (retval < 0) perror("remove shm");

    return 0;
}
```